# Approving suggested edits when the answer doesn't need any edits

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that some of the SO community makes poor reviews as the answer which has been given an edit doesn't seem to be needing of any edit.

Notice the edit history here.
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7200032

The **one liner answer I gave is already right on the spot**. But, the edits that has been approved doesn't seem to improve the quality of the answer but was modified far from what I had in mind when I gave the answer.

I have raised this subject because it might affect the quality edits SO community makes and might be that making poor approval of edits just for the sake of badges and editing just for reps doesn't seem to be right.

*EDIT:*

I find reviewers very lazy to even click the link provided.
Here is the edit note

`Comment: fixed everything`

`Using Notepad++`

Original Answer
`Save your file as filename.HTML`

Edited Answer
`Rename your file to somefilename.html`

---

I therefore conclude that the answer I have provided is already feasible and it doesn't need anymore edits. I mean why stray the answer far from the original one?

Comment: Well, people are people, and there are review audits already.

Comment: You are free to rollback the edit if you believe it doesn't match what you had in mind. I can't speak for the reviewers and their reasons for accepting, but there are audits in place to stop people who blindly review suggested edits.